# sqoop export to redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, sqoop, amazon-redshift

I was exploring option of exporting data from s3 to redshift using Sqoop. It turned out that instead of providing "--batch" option, insert was happing record by record. Can anyone help me with how I can perform batch insert to Redshift.

Thanks,
Swaroop

Answer (score 1):

To load data from S3 to redshift, you can use **copy** commands. Copy commands works in parallel and they load data faster. Also they take care of compressions.

You can use PHP, shell or java programs to load data to redshift.

Details for **copy** command are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)

Comment: Thanks Sandesh for replay. We use copy command extensively for data load but in one case where we use copy command RS disk becomes 100% full and copy fails. This is why we are looking for other alternates to load data to RS.

Comment: what is size of data that you are loading? if you have multiple files then you sep copy command for each of the file. what is node configuration you have for Redshift?

Comment: We have 256 gzip compressed files. Each of size 2.8GB which is growing everyday. RS configuration - 8 node dw2.8xlarge. To handle disk issue we have divided 256 files in 2 groups and perform copy 1 group at a time. But this is a temporary solution.

Comment: One suggestion, if you not using compression, please create your table with encoding. so that redshift will store data in compression format.By default copy will do it for you. ( apply compression)

Comment: Thanks Sandesh. We are creating table with encoding for each column.